# File Manager for TinyMCE 5 Not showing uploaded images,404 image not found,but it exists in the folder - Laravel

Tags: laravel, tinymce, file-manager

So,i've been having problems with integrating file manager to TinyMCE 5,uploading images into a specified folder using the file manager works without any issues,that is also true for deleting the images,but the problem is when you try to use the images,they appear as blank and if you open a console you will see error 404 messages that images don't exist

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is that i went to **.env** file which is inside of your laravel project and then changed this line of code which is usually located in the first few lines of the file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to this

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

It seems like file manager uses APP_URL to build the URL for some reason,still haven't found out why tho